# Upgraded to Flutter 3.13.0, Android throws "No address associated with hostname"

Tags: android, flutter, version, socketexception

Today we upgraded our Flutter project to 3.13.0. Project runs fine on iOS. On Android I'm getting this uncaught exception while debugging the project in VS code. The URL is valid. Interestingly, the app does seem to be able to hit these URLs and functions fine. But unsure why we are getting this exception all the sudden.

`SocketException (SocketException: Failed host lookup: '*************' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7))`

Tried downgrading our version back to 3.10.1 and the issue goes away. However, our build pipeline started failing on this version. We use `intl` for localizations, which needed updating for our pipeline to run. Ultimately, trying to understand how we can resolve the SocketException and stay on the newest version of Flutter.

Comment: Are you certain your AndroidManifest.xml file contains  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />. Is the error message really displaying all those asterisks?

Comment: @JohnWeidner We've had that permission in the manifest for a long time. And the error message doesn't have asterisks. I replaced my URL with asterisks for privacy.

Comment: Are you able to open that URL from a browser on your Android device?

Comment: @JohnWeidner yes, the APIs actually run successfully in the app despite the exception. If I turn off breakpoint "Uncaught Exceptions" you wouldn't even know it was happening. But still would like to understand why this started occurring.

Comment: same error in flutter 3.13.1. Any solutions ?

Comment: To get around the problem, in the breakpoints panel, uncheck "Uncaught Exceptions".  Explanation :
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126650#issuecomment-1568206432

Answer (score 2):

I get this exception thrown when running Android Studio in debug mode.
Works fine in Run mode